# can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1. (xfs)

Tags: linux, debian, mount, hard-disk, xfs

The Disk Type : xfs

Suddenly we can't access the data from the Hard Disk. We got the following error while trying to mount the disk using this command :  **mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /000**.

> mount: /000: can't read superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1.

While run the command : **fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1p1**

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p1: 477 GiB, 512109142016 bytes, 1000213168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Please help me to mount the disk.